# How to simulate "right click" in Apple MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, switching

I have very recently started using Apple for the first time. I have MacBook Pro. I am used to using windows/dell laptop/ibm thinkpad laptop.

I am not being able to understand the mouse. It is one big rectangle with a slightly elevated small rectangle below it. What is the purpose of these 2 each? Right now, both serve as a left click. How do I simulate right click?

When I wanted to click a new link in new tab, earlier I would just right click and select open in new tab. In MacBook Pro, how do I achieve it? I can do it by clicking command+ left-click. but what if I just want to be able to achieve it by only right hand and not have to use both the hands to achieve something as basic as this.

Thanks,

**Update**

I just found out that tapping with 2 fingers will simulate right click and it is working. But is that the only solution, because I am finding it very cumbersome to switch between one finger and 2 fingers tapping.
How long new users usually take to get used to this concept?

**Update**

I am able to tweak time response of touchpad as you mentioned above. I also notice that while typing (say blogging etc), if I have to go a few words back, my keyboard response to <-- key is very slow. So either I use mouse to click at desired place or wait for <-- key to reach to the place. This key response is noticeably slower than what I am used to in ibm thinkpad/dell etc. My CPU is of decent configuration, so I don't think the system speed should be a hurdle here. Any way to configure keys response time too??

Comment: Hi p2pnode - although it feels nice to add updates to a question, people that care about edits can see the entire edit history by clicking the edit time. It's also OK to answer your own question (or edit any of the questions you like to make it perfect for you) In the long run, questions that are short and detailed work best. Make the answers as long and tell the tale how you got to the best answer there rather than editing the question.

Comment: For editing you may want to try Alt+Arrow keys to move one word at a time. Cmd+Arrow Keys move to the beginning/end of the line. In the long run this may prove faster than switching between the keyboard and mouse (or trackpad). See "Application and other Mac OS X keyboard commands" in [Mac OS X keyboard shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to fine tune the behavior of your track-pad with the System Preferences panel (see Mouses, TrackPad and Keyboard).

If it's not enough, then you should have a look at [Better Touch Tool](http://www.boastr.de/). (It's free)

Comment: sorry to duplicate. I see your answer came in while I was composing mine.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to tweak time response of touchpad as you mentioned above. I also notice that while typing (say blogging etc), if I have to go a few words back, my keyboard response to <-- key is very slow. So either I use mouse to click at desired place or wait for <-- key to reach to the place. This key response is noticeably slower than what I am used to in ibm thinkpad/dell etc. My CPU is of decent configuration, so I don't think the system speed should be a hurdle here. Any way to configure keys response time too??

Comment: If you're referring to how long it takes for the arrow key to repeat, Delay until key repeat is customizable in System Preferences.

Answer (score 4):

You can activate a secondary click ("right click") by holding down control and clicking. In Lion (10.7), you can use System Preferences to configure the trackpad to use the two-finger tap, or either of the bottom two corners of the trackpad as secondary click areas. I don't have a Snow Leopard machine near me to verify what options are available in that version of the operating system. If your Macbook Pro supports multitouch (your description of the hardware sounds like it is not the latest generation, and I don't know how old yours is), there are third-party add-ons like [Better Touch Tool](http://blog.boastr.net/) that give you more options.

Answer (score 4):

As you already discovered, 2-finger tap on MacBook's trackpad is equivalent of a right mouse click. You'll get used to 2-finger taps very quickly.

Also holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> while clicking simulates right click, but again - requires a second hand (doable with one, but not too convenient).

It's worth noting that OS X Lion is full of multitouch gestures - two, three and four finger swipes that do magic. I suggest you get familiar with gestures by accessing System Preferences > Trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

To repsond to your updated question of adjustment - I find that the two finger tap is more natural when used in conjunction with the two-figure scroll gesture.  That way, your right click and your scroll are the same fingers, and you have to spend less time trying to get the right number of fingers on the trackpad.

To enable the gesture (if you haven't already) just go into System Preferences -> Trackpad & check the box to enable it.